# Unnecessary feedback banner on Close Voting and Flagging

Tags: discussion, voting, user-interface

New in the past few hours, if I vote to close something I'm given one of those totally nanny pop-ups I really didn't need.

[image: Snapshot of close pop-up]

I know my vote has been recorded. It shows in the 'close' tag right under the question I just this very second voted to close.

When flagging a post a similar pop-up is presented: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/euNgU.png]

These are as unnecessary as ["Objects in mirror are closer than they appear"](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/79261/25773) (see link for my initial incredulity that this was actually a real thing in the US.)

Could we perhaps make such things for newcomers only? For seasoned users they're just a bit much.

Comment: If you need a picture, feel free to try to close one of mine on here... I can clear that ;-) Also... the snark is kinda drowning out your point. You might want to make things a tad more neutral...

Comment: @Tinkeringbell - thank you for the offer… unfortunately I'm still considered a newbie on Meta (<3k) & can't actually raise the flag ;)) D'oh! It already seems to be a remarkably unpopular idea, -2 in  the first 3 minutes. Maybe I'm misreading the crowd here, I thought they'd all be for streamlining rather than hand-holding.

Comment: My bad. I should've known ;) Like I said, it may be the snark. And not having an actual picture probably doesn't help that much either... Perhaps just hold back on posting anything until you have such a screenshot?

Comment: The popup does close by itself  but it takes more then 6 to 8 seconds ...

Comment: I"ve probably closed the window by then anyway. It's just a "look up here" distraction & by the time I've looked, then realised I already know...

Comment: You mean [this toast notification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77myP.png), right? It’s just a confirmation and feels better than “nothing” happening. For new users (who recently reached 3k rep) this is definitely better, since they may not be familiar with the “(1)” after the “Close” link appearing. It doesn’t really feel that distracting to me. You learn to ignore it after a while.

Comment: @SebastianSimon - that's the one. I've seen similar before in other circumstances, but today's the first on a simple vtc on stacks I'm >30k

Comment: here is a screencast of the whole duration https://i.stack.imgur.com/LbX8l.gif

Comment: @Tetsujin I added the case of flagging as well, as it has the same behaviour. If you rather not have in in your question feel free to roll-back my edit.

Comment: This notification has existed for a long time, but previously, it was less visible because the "Your vote has been recorded" appeared under the Close button. The only recent change is that it now appears across the top of the page instead. I think the notification is useful because it's a clear indication that the network request has succeeded (which it sometimes doesn't, if on a poor connection) - but putting it at the top of the page does seem a bit over-the-top.

Comment: These pale-blue popups are particularly annoying when doing reviews. Each time I flag and answer, or vote to close a question, I now have to make an extra mouse click! Not all the extra gold badges are worth that.  ‎

Comment: The issue here isn't the fact of being notified that the user's vote was recorded. The issue is that the new method of notification dominates the user's attention and *requires* them to interact with it, because it blocks other information on the page which the user is looking for, and it doesn't quickly auto-dismiss. The old notification was both effective at informing the user that their vote was recorded *and* was positioned and timed such that the notification was not annoying to people who had seen it *tens of thousands* of times.

Comment: ^^ @Makyen Thank you. It is exactly that. It's now obtrusive and annoying.

Comment: Totally agree.  Give it to <2K users, like with the "consider adding a comment if you think post can be improved" note.

Comment: @Luuk thanks for the bounty!

Comment: The objects in mirror warning does serve a purpose, [people back up and rip their mirror off](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKP6W.jpg) incurring a significant repair cost; and it counts as being in an accident. If there was no warning there'd be a class-action suit claiming damages against the manufacturer; with such a warning it's difficult to claim that you didn't notice, as that places you at fault.

Comment: @Rob. It's something you learn within the first year of driving, not something you need a constant reminder of… like banners on close votes etc.

Comment: @Tetsujin, yes everyone learns something somewhere - and knows to think things through; throw away our restraints. 

Answer (score 5):

Just undo this change, please!

I navigate on mobile using the top bar, either by clicking the logo to go to the home page, clicking my profile to go back to a post I interacted with earlier, or something else. This popup makes that nearly impossible for like ten seconds:

Mobile view:
[image]

Full site view:
[image]

Comment: Do not edit just for bumping, it's abuse of the edit privilege. You can add something useful, make **useful edit**, or start a bounty on the question in order to bump it.

Comment: Well I'm still impaired by this on a daily basis, the question was idle for a month, crew hasn't responded and it was not even put under review, I'd thought I'd give it a nudge. I can't start a bounty, and putting a bounty on a question of mine has given it eight (!) views in three days.

Comment: Why can't you start a bounty? You have 1.6K rep.

Comment: Oh, I see the link now, it's under the comments, not under the Share/Edit/Follow/Flag links. Then again, my own question that I've bountied has gotten three views per day since it's bountied, feels kinda useless.

Comment: Believe me, I get your feeling and feel the same for years, seeing hundreds of bugs that can be fixed in few moments, yet nobody fix them. But still, we can't just bump all bug reports with empty edit. It is wrong.

Comment: @Shadow I agree and sorry for the edit. It just grinds my gears immensely that apparently someone at Stack Overflow thought _"I know, let's introduce annoying banners!"_, and not follow up on the annoyances this decision and implementation caused. A couple of times a day I have to snipe for the X on mobile, or hope that my fat finger can press the icon I want between the banner and the top of my browser. All because someone wanted that banner on top. With the usual lack of consistency as well, see the missing period on the second banner? Notice where the X is? *Mumbles in old man language*.

Comment: All good, thanks for understanding!

Answer (score 0):

As a new user, I don't think we need those pop ups either, please.  There could be a much smaller indicator with no text to confirm that your intended action occurred.  If you are interacting with the site, it's likely that you have already figured out how the basics work.
Also, if someone is not inclined to leave a comment and they are prompted to by the pop up, I would guess that the comment would be less thoughtful.
Just some thoughts.